# Maven taking a lot of time to run integration test

Tags: java, spring, maven

The Maven build for my project is taking aroung 25 mins to run the full build . Bulk of the time is taken by the integration tests to run.

On the other hand the same integration tests take under 2 mins to run when i run the test cases manually on eclipse.

I feel that the spring context is loaded for every test case in maven but once on eclipse.

Is there any setting which does this?

Comment: Please include the relevant parts of your Spring `context.xml`, your `pom.xml`, and your test classes.

Comment: Unfortunately i cant share the code here due to company restrictions.But to give a heads up it just a normal spring integration test case.

Comment: Then we are unable to help you.

Comment: But is there any perticular setting in spring context which says to load the context once or every time for all the tests?

Comment: No, there isn't. A Spring context is loaded every time something loads it. But we could help you better if you at least provide *some* hint what your code and configuration looks like.

Comment: I would suggest to take a look for TestNG and make a `@BeforeTest` to prevent setting up for every test case. This can be improved by using `@BeforeGroup` for a group of integration tests.

Comment: You are comparing two different scenarios like a full build and running integration tests (How many integration tests do you have?).

Answer (score 1):

Spring Framework has [Context Caching](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.3.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#testcontext-ctx-management-caching) feature that is designed to solve this kind of problems. Be aware that your case can change context, there is a feature for this too, it is `@DirtiesContext` annotation.

Forking tests (especially fork per test) with Maven may be an obstacle in using this feature.